# How to dynamically display the Menu options based on role

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to load the menu items based on the role ?.

ex: i have a json like

```
    `let menu=[
     {
      "id":"navigation",
      "title":"Navigation",
      "type":"group"
     },
     {
      "id":"usermgmt",
      "title":"User Management",
      "type":"item"
     },
     {
      "id":"profile",
      "title":"User Management",
      "type":"item"
     }
  ]`
```

And I want to load the all the menu's for admin role and I want to load only profile to user role .(The menu item are not  limited only to above menu items, there will be more menu items for admin and user). I need to extract the  menu items dynamically from the above JSON according to the role . How to achieve it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? where did you stuck? And this is just a template string. It is not JSON.

Comment: please describe more about  what you did so far ?

Comment: I am asking for ideas to do it efficiently , I could add a new key for  each elements "admin":true/false display those menu  which have true.

Comment: Instead of adding new key like 'admin: true/false' to this array, I would prefer maintaining a different arrays for User and Admin like - User = ['navigation', 'usermgmt'] and Admin = [navigation', 'profile'] so that u need not maintain multiple keys in your array and later if a new role like (eg. Support Person) comes, all you have to do is add a new array for that role and your original navigation array is not touched.

Comment: This would work fine but in future if are renaming "navigation" then we would need to do it in 2 places ,which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing. I believe you didn't mean to put a string in that  menu variable.

Do you know for example what is the relation between the menu and roles beforehand? For example, if you have

```
const permissions = {
  admin: ["navigation", "usermgmt", "profile"],
  user: ["profile"],
  manager: ["usermgmt"]
}
```

Then I would `filter()` based on those permissions

Comment: This would work fine but in future if are renaming profile then we would need to do it in 2 places ,which I am trying to avoid.